# How to access file/image from Stripe API

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I'm using the Stripe API (with node)

I hit the account endpoint which includes a logo id in the repsonse.

I then attempt to get that file, as the [Stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/retrieve) describe:

```
await generalConfig.stripe.files.retrieve(req.session.user.data.logo, { stripeAccount: 'connected-account-id' });
```

Response:

```
fileLink {
  id: 'file_1MVfHl8uSxUnuB3iogeBSRco',
  object: 'file',
  created: 1675015645,
  expires_at: null,
  filename: 'Logo.png',
  links: {
    object: 'list',
    data: [ [Object] ],
    has_more: false,
    url: '/v1/file_links?file=file_1MVfHl8uSxUnuB3iogeBSRco'
  },
  purpose: 'business_logo',
  size: 7814,
  title: null,
  type: 'png',
  url: 'https://files.stripe.com/v1/files/file_1MVfHl8uSxUnuB3iogeBSRco/contents'
}
```

I can't figure out how to actually access the image from that info. I tried various URLs from that data with no luck.

I also noticed the [Stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/file_links) show that it should return a response that includes a full URL like this:

```
"url": "https://files.stripe.com/links/MDB8YWNjdF8xMDMyRDgyZVp2S1lsbzJDfGZsX3Rlc3RfSGI4OVcxcVQzTmM3ZVdFdFVxUzF5aU5l007JOZUEx5"
```

...but it doesn't.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the doc, you can download the file through the [url](https://stripe.com/docs/api/files/object#file_object-url) property. If you can't download the file, I'd suggest you to reach out to [Stripe support](https://stripe.com/docs/api/files/object#file_object-url) for help.